# Did some Shuttle flights really have no spacesuits aboard?

Tags: space-shuttle, spacesuits

According to [this source](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/20120014266), pages 378-382 and 406, there were no launch suits for Shuttle missions STS-5 through STS-33.  Instead, crew literally wore shirtsleeves during launch and re-entry, plus anti-G pants under their coveralls, and a small helmet called the [Launch Escape Helmet](http://www.astronautix.com/l/lehhelmet.html).

Since many of these missions had no EVAs, **does this mean that some Shuttle missions carried no spacesuits?**

[image: training with the Launch Escape Helmet]

> The Launch Entry Helmet (LEH) was donned via an unusual “clamshell” hinging mechanism that divided the helmet into joinable fore-and-aft, semi-hemispherical sections.  [...]  The resulting helmet, perhaps unsurprisingly, looked much like a full-pressure suit helmet, but it was not.
>
> p. 378

[image: Launch Entry Helmet]

Even worse, the helmet had been previously tested and rejected by both the U.S. Navy and U.S. Air Force.

> In reality, the only protection the helmet provided was against ambient noise during ascent, incidental bumping of the head against the inside of the crew module, and possible smoke in the cockpit.
>
> p. 381